# Extra vertical scrolling in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm working on a website which is working perfectly on every browser except firefox. In firefox extra space is added at the end and an extra vertical scrolling is there. My website is hosted [here](https://projects-sushilkumar.rhcloud.com/geodine/). Can anyone please tell me whats going wrong.

Comment: First thing I'd do is clean up the errors. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fprojects-sushilkumar.rhcloud.com%2Fgeodine%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0):

The I frame could be causing it. If you add

```
Style="position:fixed;"
```

in a div serving as the back ground like this

```
<html><head><title>your title</title></head><body>
<div Style="position:fixed;" name="entire web page">

<p><h1>HI and welcome to my world</p>
<div>some content...</div>
</div>
```

You might also add it to any "big" items like large pictures 
it will also help if to make sure all of your appending** height percentage add up to no more than 100% trying to display 140% of a screen means it needs a scroll bar. a have had this trouble me for days before. **Any object that is stacked on top of another.